# Problems with venv & localhost when automating deployment with .bat file

Tags: batch-file, flask, virtualenv

I am trying to create a batch file, to launch my app with one click on Windows. I have:

```
cd "C:\Users\<project_dir>"
venv\scripts\activate
python __init__.py
start /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\" chrome.exe localhost:5000
```

Problem 1: Although `venv\scripts\activate` works manually, it does not work in the batch file (I've also tried `start /d`).

Problem 2: launching the Flask server with `python __init__.py` causes the batch script to pause, so that the browser is never launched.

Comment: Can you please specify what `venv\scripts\activate` is meant to do.

Comment: It launches the virtual environment in Windows (http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/installation/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
cd "C:\Users\<project_dir>"
start venv\scripts\python __init__.py
start /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\" chrome.exe localhost:5000
```

I have addressed your problem #1 by using the virtual environment directly, without activating it. You can also do `call venv\scripts\activate` and then invoke your script with `start python __init__.py`.

The problem #2 is solved by running the server via `start` so that it spawns a new process.

Comment: Thanks, Miguel. It does, albeit by opening the Python (command line) while closing the Command Prompt. Any idea how I might do this from within Command Prompt? Useful for stopping and restarting the server.

Comment: Try using `pythonw` instead of `python`.

Comment: Thanks. That contains the script to Command Prompt but Command Prompt still closes. Is there a way to keep Command Prompt open (as it does when commands are entered manually)?